# How to read all .txt files in a directory in C

Tags: c, file, directory

I currently have a short program to read and sort a text tile in C.

If I want to read many files, is there a substitute for:

`FILE *f
f = fopen("*.txt", "rw");`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explore `findfirst` and `findnext` (MSVC) and their variants.

Comment: This is a very OS-specific function. In linux, you use the "dirent" family of functions.

Comment: Apart from being too broad (did you even try anything?), there are tons of similar questions on SO with answers for Linux, plain DOS and Windows. Pick any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f = fopen("*.txt", "rw"); won't work in any case.

The usual way to do this probably depends on your operating system. On Unix-like systems, the simple way is to invoke your program with a command line like "my_pgm *.txt" and let the shell find the matching files. (You'll get multiple arguments, each one being a file name.) I understand that microsoft OSes would require the program to find the files itself.

To do that more or less portably, I'd probably use opendir() and readdir() to examine directory entries and see whether they matched the desired pattern.